# Retrieving a json from a website where direct access to a page isn't allowed

Tags: python, json, graph

I'm trying to obtain the data contained within the graph on [this website](http://www.grandexchangecentral.com/item.php?rid=10350). I used Firebug to find the direct link to the json and used this script (which works on other direct json links). What should be returned is a set of timestamps and prices.

```
    import urllib2
    import simplejson
    req = urllib2.Request("http://www.grandexchangecentral.com/include/gecgraphjson.php?jsid=10350")
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    f = opener.open(req)
    h = simplejson.load(f)
```

Running this script returns `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`. I can get the data manually with Firebug, but I'd like to sort through multiple data sets with a script. Is there a way to get this data without receiving an HTTP error?

Comment: You probably need to set the proper headers. Do you log in before visiting this page?

Comment: Are you following a particular path in Firebug? When I try to open it manually one of the error messages I receive is "You may be trying to access this page directly" (and as @Blender says, there is also user-account-related text).

Comment: I get the same error while logged in to the website. What sort of headers should I be looking for if what I have might be wrong? And yes, I'm following a particular path and opening a link returns what you said.

Comment: Hmm... So what steps do you normally follow to access this data?

Comment: I can find what I'm looking for manually by opening Firebug->Net, clicking on GET gecgraphjson.php?jsid=10350 and clicking on either 'Responses' or 'Json'. Both of them have the relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website looks for the `Referer` header and tries to make sure that the request originated from one of its webpages. This isn't a great security measure, so it's really easy to bypass.

I'm a bit lazy right now and don't want to look up the documentation for `urllib2`, so here's a solution with the `requests` module:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.grandexchangecentral.com/include/gecgraphjson.php?jsid=10350'
r = requests.get(url, headers={'Referer': 'www.grandexchangecentral.com'})

data = r.json
```

Comment: That works until the last line, which gives me this `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'text'`. Actually, the website isn't letting me access it at all right now, but the error doesn't come until the end.

Comment: What version of requests are you using? Try `print request` and see what it returns.

Comment: 0.8.2-1. I'll see if there's a new one.

Comment: I see. I'm getting an error accessing the site right now (happens as a result of too many direct requests). I'll upgrade requests and try both of your suggestions. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: No problem. The code works for me, so I don't think it should do anything different for you once their server stops blocking your requests.

Comment: you could use `request.json`. It handles character encoding correctly for json content unlike `request.text`. Also the names could be better: `json` is a module, don't shadow it (you could use `data`), `request` and `requests` are too similar, just `r` instead of `request` would be enough.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thanks for catching that.

Comment: btw, `r` stands for `response`, not `request`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stdlib-only version, just add headers as @Blender suggested:

```
import json
import urllib2

url = "http://www.grandexchangecentral.com/include/gecgraphjson.php?jsid=10350"
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'Referer': 'www.grandexchangecentral.com'})
page = urllib2.urlopen(req) # assume no multithreading
data = json.load(page) # assume utf-8 encoding
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you'll be able to. When trying to access that link this is the error I get.

> Changes not allowed.  You may be trying to access this page directly.  Or you may have a browser that does not send correct referer information. We require this information to validate member account editing. Please use the proper membership editing page, or use a different browser.

You are either going to have to get your script to fake logging in to the site or play with the headers. Alternatively, you can try and ask the site owners if you could get access to pull their data.